# angular script template with module doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

i have code like this

```
    <div ng-app="">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
            I am from a template.
        </script>
        <div ng-include="'/tpl.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <script> angular.module('a', []);</script>
    <div ng-app="a">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpla.html">
            I am from a template a.
        </script>
        <div ng-include="'/tpla.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <script> angular.module('b', []).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {});</script>
    <div ng-app="b" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tplb.html">
            I am from a template b.
        </script>
        <div ng-include="'/tplb.html'"></div>
    </div>
```

the output is :

> I am from a template.

why when i use "ng-include" inside a module it doesn't work? do i missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular considers only the first found [`ng-app`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) attribute when it bootstraps the application. The second one `ng-app="a"` is simply ignored.

If you want to have multiple Angular applications on the same page, you will need to bootstrap them manually (without using ngApp directive) using [angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) method.